# NFC Can I send NdefMessage via button pressed?

Tags: android, nfc

In Android API level 10, NfcAdapter has a method enableForegroundNdefPush(),

and the description is

```
You must explicitly call this method every time the activity is resumed,
and you must call disableForegroundNdefPush(Activity) before your activity
completes onPause().
```

So enableForegroundNdefPush() can only be called onResume()?

But I want to send NdefMessage when a button is pressed

How can i do ?

Comment: But why oh why would you not send NdefMessage as a tag or device enters range?